# Checkbox to select various months

Tags: vba, excel

Within a userform, I'm coding a checkbox to select multiple other checkboxes (months). This is to enable the user to select all 12 months rather than clicking through each of them. Following is the code I've written. What have I done wrong now?

```
Private Sub Selectbox_AfterUpdate()
Dim x As Integer

If Me.Selectbox.Value = True Then
For x = 0 To 12
Me.Controls("Month" & x).Value = True
Next x
Me.Selectbox.Caption = "Deselect All"

ElseIf Me.Selectbox.Value = False Then
For x = 0 To 12
Me.Controls("Month" & x).Value = False

Next x
Me.Selectbox.Caption = "Select All"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't check against True or False, check against vbChecked or vbUnchecked.

Comment: I tried that. It gives me a run-time error, suggesting "could not find the specified object"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 12 month. Change

```
For x = 0 To 12
```

to

```
For x = 1 To 12
```

It's depend the name you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Don't check against True or False, check against vbChecked or vbUnchecked.  You also have 1 too many iterations on your loop.  Your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub Selectbox_AfterUpdate()
   Dim x As Integer

   If Me.Selectbox.Value = vbChecked Then
      For x = 1 To 12
         Me.Controls("Month" & x).Value = vbChecked
      Next x

      Me.Selectbox.Caption = "Deselect All"
   ElseIf Me.Selectbox.Value = vbUnchecked Then
      For x = 1 To 12
         Me.Controls("Month" & x).Value = vbUnchecked
      Next x

      Me.Selectbox.Caption = "Select All"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could do it all with 1 loop. `Me.Controls("Month" & x).Value = Me.Selectbox.Value`

Comment: You are correct.  I was just keeping the OP's original formatting.

Comment: Oh I see now.   You would need to `Me.Selectbox.Caption = IIf(Me.Selectbox.Value, "Select All", "Deselect All")`.  I guess your way is just as good.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments. Great help. Can't believe it was as simple as 0 to 1.